# Peskin and Schroeder: Dirac algebra for compton scattering

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

on Peskin and Schroeder at page 159 above eq. (5.74) I find this relation
$$(\displaystyle{\not} p +m)\gamma^\nu u(p)=(2p^\nu -\gamma^\nu\displaystyle{\not} p+\gamma^\nu m)u(p)$$
and I can't understand how to derive this relation. I thought about the anticommutator of gamma matrices
$$\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$$ but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Contract the anticommutation relation with $p_\mu$ and see what you obtain.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the $\gamma\cdot p\gamma^{\nu}=p_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}=p_{\mu}(2\eta^{\mu\nu}-\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu})$, where I have used the anticommutation relation you are referring to. If something is not clear, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: I think this is the solution! Thanks, later I'll try with the calculation!

Comment: My question is now: can I freely move $p_\mu$, namely can I do the following $$\gamma^\mu p_\mu\gamma^\nu=p_\mu\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu$$

Comment: Yes, since every component of $p_{\mu}$ is actually a scalar quantity, in contrast with the components of $\gamma^{\mu}$ or $\gamma^{\nu}$, which are matrices and in general do not commute

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is that it is a bit hard to understand the lorentz and the spinors indices so I have some problems with that. Thanks, now I see the point!